# Bluetooth on WP8

Tags: bluetooth, keyboard

Does anyone know if the bluetooth connectivity has been extended to more devices in Windows Phone 8?

Specifically, I'm interested in

1. Knowing whether bluetooth keyboards will be supported, and
2. Knowing if bluetooth heart monitors will be supported (so that [Sports Tracker](http://shop.sports-tracker.com/heart-rate-monitors.html) can finally make a Windows Phone model)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Bluetooth keyboards are currently not supported by the operating system since it lacks the corresponding profile (HID). Refer to this list to see all available profiles: https://www.bluetooth.org/tpg/QLI_viewQDL.cfm?qid=19535
2. I read that Windows Phone 8 provides developers with the ability to access the Bluetooth stack through an API to enable "App to device" communications. (Refer: http://www.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-8-feature-expanded-bluetooth-functionality-access-stack-and-transfer). Unfortunately I don't have a deep understanding of how Bluetooth works but I think this could mean heart rate monitors can work if the app supports it.

Comment: yes they work flawlessly I'm typing this on one now.
you just pair them using a pin code and press enter